# Copying file to windows ce device using c#

Tags: c#, windows-ce, rapi

I have a portable windows ce device. I am writing an application to copy files from windows 7 to windows ce using RAPI. 
This is the code i use.

```
Mobile.Device.CopyFileToDevice(@"C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\AssetList.xml”, @“\Flash Disk\AMM\AssetList.xml”);
```

Both paths and files exist. When it reaches that line of code it throws an error

```
 "object reference not set to an instance of an object".
```

When i look on the device a AssetList.xml gets created with 0 kb . Please help.

Comment: Is this your real code? you have missed `"` at the beginning of path

Comment: Sorry, code has variables. i will edit.

Answer (score 0):

One of your problems is that you are missing a quote ***"***. Your code should not even compile, so change

```
Mobile.Device.CopyFileToDevice(C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\AssetList.xml"
```

to

```
Mobile.Device.CopyFileToDevice("C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\AssetList.xml"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
    RAPI rapi = new RAPI();
    rapi.Connect(true, 10);
    rapi.CopyFileToDevice(localFile, remoteFile, true);
```

Comment: @LuckyLuke2 : have you connected the PDA properly to your PC using Active Sync, please check the connection properly.